# Export data with complex queries command line mysql

Tags: mysql, csv

I'm retrieving data from MYSQL databases with a .bat file. The bat file have the next structure

```
mysql.exe -b -r -u USER -pPASSWORD DATABASE  -h IP -e "QUERY"  > "PATH\example.txt"
```

My problem is with complicate queries. I have a query wit multiples joins, and another with asterisk, but doesn't work. I can run the queries perfectly in Navicat but in command line like the code above is impossible. 
It is there a way to run this queries without changing the methodology of command line?.

The queries usually have inner join and left joins

Comment: You could make a text file containing your queries and run the file with the `mysql` command, then redirect that output like you have shown

Comment: Yes I have the next error: ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\U'
I have deleted all line breaks and paragraph breaks.

Comment: Are you running it like `mysql < script-file > mysql.out`? Read here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/batch-mode.html

Comment: @cricket_007 works great!. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of providing the query through the `-e`valulation flag as a string, you could provide a SQL script file instead for reusability, then direct that in as standard-in to be executed by `mysql`, then direct the standard-out like you have been doing.

All-in-all, something like this

```
shell> mysql -b -s -r --username=USER --password=PASSWORD -h HOST db_name < script.sql > output.tab
```